# I can't find my alias file

Tags: alias, zsh

Some time ago I created an alias which is still working

```
(base) Mac-mini ~ % type Iridis

Iridis is an alias for ssh ...
```

I want to modify this alias but when I go to `nano ~/.bashrc` the file is empty. Perhaps I saved it in another file? How can I find it?

Comment: It looks like you are using zsh there not bash - have you checked `~/.zshrc` ?

Comment: Exactly, thanks. How do you know I am using zsh? come with Mac??

Comment: The output of the `type` command would be slightly different in bash (`Idris is aliased to ...` and also the `%` prompt is more typical of zsh

Answer (score 0):

Macs come with Zsh shell by default, so you have to edit `~/.zshrc`.

Zsh has many types of aliases. You may have to add some things for it to be:

1 - Global

`alias -g <your_alias>="<your_command>"`

2 - Parameterized

```
<alias-name>() {
    <command> $param $param2
}
```

3 - Suffix

`alias -s <extension>="<preferred-tool>"`

4 - Simple

`alias <your_alias>="<commands>"`

You may want to check [this site too](https://www.thorsten-hans.com/5-types-of-zsh-aliases).

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is to print out the entire shell invocation and  `grep`ing through to find the file source by running:

```bsh
zsh -ixc : 2>&1 | grep "pattern"
```

In your case this would be:

```bsh
zsh -ixc : 2>&1 | grep "Iridis"
```

You should see a `grep` result that shows what file this string is defined in.